# Daemon process cannot survive suspend

Tags: c, linux, daemon

I am writing daemon application for Debian Sid. It works perfectly most of the times, but dies silently after i put my laptop to suspend (or hibernate). So i have a couple of questions:

1. What should I Google for solutions?
2. Maybe, you have any ideas what is going on?

Comment: `setsid` and `nohup` are your Google keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daemon's loop was on blocking read call, and suspend (hibernate) interrupts it. So, should check errnos more accurately.
Fixed by adding:

```
if ( errno == EINTR ) continue;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `strace`-ing the daemon to see what is the reason it dies silently. Generally, suspend/hibernate alone should have no effect on user processes.